# How to make multiple timers running in different way within its own JLabel in java

Tags: java, timer

when I clicked timeIn in slot 1 the timer start,but when i clicked another timeIn in other slot the timer in slot 1 stopped then the current running timer was... I dunno why it runs crazy @.@

Comment: What is timeIn and what slots are you referring to?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, it's a JButton with actionListener directly to the timer.

Comment: Im making a PARKING LOT GUI application,I have slot1-slot10 it's a JTextField.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Sorry bro, I got the solution already :) anyway thanks to your time.  :)

Comment: You should post the solution to your problem as answer then.